# Ecto query unique through a belongs_to association?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two models `Event` and `Customer`. The relationship is that an Event `belongs_to` a Customer, which can `has_many` Events.

Now, I need to return the count of unique Customers by way of Events, which fall in a particular date range. Does Ecto have any query method that can do what I need?

Comment: It is not super clear what data do you want returned. Perhaps you want a group_by on the customer_id? Or perhaps distinct: true?

Comment: Hi @JoséValim, thanks for replying. I needed to return the count of unique Customers given a set of Events. I managed to do this without having to preload or join the Customer to Events, since I could use `distinct: event.customer_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this without having to preload or join the Customer to Events, since I could use distinct: event.customer_id